# Syntax error when using the default-autowire-candidates and the primary property inside a bean

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

Can you still use the default-autowire-candidates in the default bean, inside the beans.xml file (the syntax is highlighted as an error) and is the primary property inside a bean still used ?

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd"
            default-autowire="byType"
            default-autowire-candidates = "consoleWriter,fileWriter">

            <bean id="logger" class="com.dylan.spring.test.Logger">
            </bean>

            <bean name="consoleWriter"
                class="com.dylan.spring.test.ConsoleWriter" 
                primary= "true">
            </bean>

            <bean name="panda" class="com.dylan.spring.test.ConsoleWriter">
            </bean>


            <bean name="fileWriter" class="com.dylan.spring.test.FileWriter">
            </bean>

            <bean name="squirrel" class="com.dylan.spring.test.FileWriter"
                autowire-candidate="false">
            </bean>

        </beans>
```

Comment: Don't XML attributes need to be quoted?

Comment: Yes I know theres a mistake in the code I posted the consoleWriter and fileWriter attributes should be quoted but thats not the problem here, every time I try to type in the default-autowire-candidates keyword or the primary keyword, it gives me a syntax error. I cant really understand why, maybe these features are no longer available in the newer version of Spring?

Comment: What's the specific error?

Comment: the default-autowire-candidates and the primary are not being recognized as an option/property as if they don't exist I even tried to add the property with auto complete (ctrl + space) in eclipse and either of these properties showed up !

Comment: You should include what version of Spring you're using, no? Your XSD indicates spring-beans 2.0 (?!) and no spring-context.

Comment: Figured out the problem , the newer version might not support these tags

Comment: changed this bit xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://schema.spring.io/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

Comment: Newer meaning...? The link is for 4.0.

Comment: Yes thats seemed to work : )